# calculating $\frac{1}{1-\cos^2 (x)}-\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm stuck on simplifying this equation, and would appreciate your support on my approach.

$\frac{1}{1-\cos^2 (x)}-\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}$

My working out:

Using the identity: $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2 (x)$ and $\frac{1}{\sin^2 (x)}=\csc^2(x)$

$$\csc^2(x)-\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)} = \frac{1-[\csc^2(x)+\csc^2(x)\cos^2(x)]}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\frac{[1-\csc^2(x)]-\csc^2(x)\cos^2(x)]}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\frac{-\cot^2(x)-\csc^2(x)\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}=-\frac{\csc^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Succinctly, it's $\frac{2\cos^2x}{(1-\cos^2x)(1+\cos^2x)}=\frac{2\cot^2x}{1+\cos^2x}$. You've miscalculated; in your display-line equation, the first $=$ has multiplied its RHS by $-1$. Note also $\csc^2x\cos^2x=\cot^2x$.

Comment: I question the interest of the exercise, the final expression is not much more appealing than the starting one...

Comment: You're right! I for some reason introduced an extra $csc^2(x)$ into the numerator which messed up my output. This was to help me tackle a longer equation.